# Alternative to displaying multiple plan columns

Tags: gui-design, tables, desktop-application, multi-column

I'm working on a pricing page that has 6 different plans. What is the optimal way of displaying them considering the limited amount of space we have?

Mobile isn't an issue since they will just be stacked, but on Desktop, our space is limited to around 1200px.

What are some suggestions you might have to display all the plans and make sure each one of them is discoverable?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First, as Zasul has said, you should probably try limiting your plans in the first place. Too many choices can lead to decision fatigue and your potential customers may end up choosing none at all. Perhaps you could simply to just "Plan 1", "Plan 2", "Custom plan" where with custom plan they can just speak with a representative and set up a plan that fits their needs.

The other solution that I would recommend, is to pick your "Top 3" plans either in terms of popularity or your most ecompassing (cheapest, middle, most expensive) and highlight those in the highlighted card layout and then stacking the remaining plans underneath, like this:
[image]

This will allow your visitors to view all of your options while hopefully reducing decision fatigue as they'll think they should probably just choose from the Top 3.

If you must display all plans at the same visual weight then I don't see any option other than condensing the cards as much as possible and then stacking them at the point when they no longer fit horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have too many price plans. You should limit to 3 - 4 or maximum 5, but when having 5 you should already display filters and ways to help the user read trough. Ask the business owner if he thinks this is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to start a new row. However, the second row will receive less attention than the first and maybe that's not something you want. So one could argue that showing them next to each other is hierarchically the best way. But, as you already said, space is limited and 6 options won't fit.

A few solutions I can think off:

- Could you remove plans by asking the user one or two simple
  questions? I don't know how the plans differ from one another, but my
  guess is that not every plan is optimal for everybody. Try to get rid
  of some plans by asking 1 or 2 simple questions.
- Limit the number of plans you offer. This might seem a bit radical,
  but it could very well be the best approach. For a user, choosing between 3
  options is easier than choosing between 6. A lot of research has been
  done about this. Search for 'pricing strategies in marketing' and
  you'll find a lot of information. (Try not to be evil ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Im always fun of the horizontal alignment in situations like this. Much better for stacking for tablet and mobile, also better for if you need to expand boxes and display more content.